# Problemas con la Libreria Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask

Hola comunidad soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y quiero perdirles su ayuda estoy trabajando un proyecto con Python y Flask y estoy trabado en un error que no consigo como solucionarlo.

Ya tengo mi entorno virtual.
instale la libreria mediante el comando pip install flask-sqlalchemy
y cuando voy a llamar a libreria me genera error
(from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy)
en esta linea como si no me reconociera la libreria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: Instalaste en el entorno virtual o globalmente?

Comment: Todo lo instale en el entorno virtual

Comment: Pudiste solucionar el error?. Si es así por favor comparte la solución. Gracias.